# How does Github deal with several code updates?

Tags: git, github

I want to do a project with a friend of mine and we want to use GitHub. I have already set up a repository and checked out the pull/push stuff, but there was a question that came to my mind.

Let's pretend we are working on the project at the same time and we both pulled the latest Version from Github. Now we change some stuff, add features and so on in different classes and then push it on Github again. Will everything be changed on GitHub? Since how does GitHub know what code to overwrite and what not? If I made changes to a class and push it to GitHub and my friend does not have this changes in the class and pushes after me with his changes on a different class, the changes from my edited class are undone, aren't they?

Comment: This is not a good question.  You need to read up on the git documentation and come back with some specifics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no research has been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of using source control is not to lose any work (new/changes).
And git accomplish this using commits.

so if you push with force flag to override the changes of other person, your commit will be on HEAD and that state of code will be visible, other person changes are still there in a commit.

If you need to integrate both changes, the method is simple, pull changes from remote, merge to your branch, and push it back.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you try to push, after someone else pushed, you get an error that this is not a fast-forward update. You can force-push if the Git-server allows it (GitHub does), then the changes the other person pushed would be gone. But usually you fetch the changes the other person did and either merge them into your local branch or rebase your local branch upon the incoming changes before you push.